# Six different '?' characters in ASCII?

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino, ascii

I have written an Arduino program that reads GameBoy carts, Java sends it a character to start and it starts reading and sending bytes back. Opening the dumped rom in a hex editor (or even a text editor) shows they are the same at first glance, after using the compare function in the editor it highlights that all 0x3F characters in the dumped rom are incorrect - only them. 
Every feature that my Arduino program has has been tested before doing this so the only thing I could think of was to test the Java side.
To test this I simply made another simple Arduino program that sends every ascii character (0-255) over serial next to its decimal number. I realised that there were in fact six different representations of the ? character, here is those parts of the file:

```
59: ;
60: <
61: =
62: >
63: ? <
64: @
65: A
66: B
...
125: }
126: ~
127: 
128: €
129: ? <
130: ‚
131: ƒ
132: „
...
140: Œ
141: ? <
142: Ž
143: ? <
144: ? <
145: ‘
146: ’
147: “
...
154: š
155: ›
156: œ
157: ? <
158: ž
159: Ÿ
160:
```

Here is the Java code in question:

```
final Arduino board = new Arduino("COM5", 115200);
BufferedWriter rom = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("[ROM].gb"));
board.write((byte)0);
Thread.sleep(10000);
while (board.hasavailable() > 0) {
    String data = new String(board.read(board.hasavailable()));
    rom.write(data);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
rom.flush();
rom.close();
```

I cannot see this being an issue with communication as if the baud rate was wrong it would be garbage, surely the same would go for if this was a text format problem like UTF-8 to ASCII...
Basically Java must be getting confused with the '?' character and always assuming it's the first instance. Am I missing something when casting the byte[] to a string because it seems this is an obvious problem of doing it the way I am.

**EDIT 1:**

I have been using asciitable.com as a referance to get all the characters to be the same.

I also discovered that if I change the file writing code to this:

```
byte[] data = board.read(readsize);
for (byte in : data)
    rom.write(in);
```

all of the extended set (128+) become '?'s. Could it be an issue with the bufferedWriter?

**Edit 2: Reproducible example**

Here is the Arduino and Java code I am using.

http://pastebin.com/Tijjdb0A

After Java has wrote the file check it in a hex editor and see that the characters mentioned above have all been changed to 0x3F.

Comment: Where are you printing the characters? Maybe that device can't print those characters and uses `?` as default output.

Comment: Also, [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) are ascii and extended ascii tables.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis At the end I did say that those bytes are actually 0x3F instead of any of the other values of '?'. And I have been looking at that page repeatedly; as they show, Java is in-fact assuming the wrong character.

Comment: Can you give us a small reproducible example? I very much doubt Java is to blame.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sure, Thats what i'm working on now - the simplest thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are converting raw data from bytes to a String, and then only write the string to the buffered writer. When you call `new String(byte[])`, it, according to the docs

```
Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset.
```

This means that it takes your bytes, assumes it is a string in whatever the default charset is on your machine, then converts it to UTF-16, which is the internal representation of Strings in Java. On many platforms "the default charset" means UTF-8, and in UTF-8 most bytes of the "extended ASCII", i.e. 128 and higher, are parts of longer characters, that occupy more than one byte. Your bytes are probably not a valid UTF-8 string, so some of the characters get corrupted.

I think if you directly write bytes to your file, instead of making a string first, i.e. using `BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream)`, not `BufferedWriter(FileWriter)`, everything will be fine.

Comment: Ok...That sounds unnecessarily complicated. I used a FileOutoutStream  and it works (,I haven't buffered it yet). I guess because it accepts raw byte lists.

Answer (score 0):

"every ascii character (0-255)": At the least you don't have an understanding of what ASCII is. But you shouldn't need to; It's obsolete. €, ..., Ÿ, ... are not ASCII.

If you want to treat arbitrary bytes as characters, one byte per character, you need a character set that has at least 256 characters and has an encoding that uses 0-255 as one-byte characters. Try CP437. Java handles it well. Look at [OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you're happy with the other answers provided. Just to clear up the misconception posed by the question title:

> Six different '?' characters in ASCII?

No, there is not more than one question mark in ASCII. ASCII only assigns characters to values 0 thru 127, and only one of those (decimal 63) is the question mark. There are many "extensions" to ASCII that assign characters to positions 128 thru 255, but even then some values may be unassigned.

The five extra question marks you are seeing in your output correspond to unassigned positions in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Windows-1252 is the default character set in (North American editions of) Microsoft Windows, so it comes into play when you use Reader or Writer classes, or the String constructor, without specifying a character set.

When Java converts bytes to characters (or vice versa) and encounters "malformed-input or unmappable-character sequences," it uses the question mark as a replacement character. This is hinted at in the [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) Javadoc, but not really well explained there.